# Enter response once prompt returns?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, command-line, bash

It's neither a secure idea nor one I'd recommend elsewhere, but I have a situation when occasionally it takes a while for my Ansible ad-hoc command to respond. I'd love to pipe or args or whatever is needed to push the required text into the prompt so I can walk away and know it will finish.

Ex:

```
$ ansible all -m shell -a "reboot" --ask-pass
Password:
blah blah blah it worked
```

I'd love to send an argument or `<<` or something to get the password in. Is that possible?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Pre-authorise sudo? (So it can be run later)](http://superuser.com/questions/640491/pre-authorise-sudo-so-it-can-be-run-later)

Comment: Good link @G-Man. Feels like a different goal though -- I can remove the sudo to clarify. It's just about the sending of text back to a pending command prompt, no more.

Comment: If the goal is a shutdown or reboot after hours of unattended operation, then I think at least one or two of the answers there should work for you. If it's just about providing input to a long-delayed tty read, then why not just type the input in advance? You don't need to wait until some process issues a prompt and starts reading.

Comment: @mjb: What about [Expect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expect)?

Comment: @g-man I'm talking about the latter - delayed tty. I type out the prompt reply and hit enter, though sometimes it doesn't seem to catch the input. I don't want to take that chance if there's a better solution.

Comment: Well, I don't understand why typing in advance would fail, but Expect is probably a good option. At the very least, if it doesn't work correctly, it will probably log the reason why.

Comment: @cYrus I'm not familiar with Expect just yet - I'll look at it.

Comment: If Expect will work, could you leave recommended usage as an answer so I can choose it @cYrus? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Expect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expect) for such tasks.

Here's a starting point:

```
spawn ansible all -m shell -a "reboot" --ask-pass
expect "Password:"
send "secret\r"
expect eof # from this point it depends on the behavior of Ansible...
```

Save this snippet to a file, say `reboot-ansimble.sh`, then run it with:

```
expect reboot-ansimble.sh
```

PS: If [Expect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expect) is not installed you should be able to fetch it from default repositories:

```
sudo apt-get install expect
```

Answer (score 0):

May I suggest switching to key-based authentication? https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-ssh-key-based-authentication-on-a-linux-server

Key based auth allows you to log into a server without a password, and is far more secure than passwords. I have a role in Ansible Galaxy for managing users and keys here: https://galaxy.ansible.com/list#/roles/4840

Comment: this is not answering the question, since you are showing only partial solution for the provided example.

Comment: While it doesn't answer the specific question, I think it solves the problem much better.

Comment: yes. Problem in this one example. But not general problem, if you want to wait for something else. And this is the problem.