# What is a good way to initiate `sudo` on demand, so it asks for my password now (when it's convenient) and not later (when it's inconvenient)?

Tags: linux, command-line, sudo, credentials

This is hackish.

I sometimes need to quickly run programs one after the other in the terminal with some commands needing `sudo` while others do not, such as:

```
$ command1; c2; sudo c3 | c4; c5 | sudo c6; c7; sudo c8
```

I would like to initiate `sudo` (aka type the password) before `command1` so that there will be no bottleneck in `c3` waiting for the password.

Most of the time, I initiate `sudo` using a random command I haphazardly typed in the keyboard, like:

```
$ sudo laksdfjlskjf; command1; c2; sudo c3 | c4; c5 | sudo c6; c7; sudo c8
```

It says `command not found` for `laksdfjlskjf`, but I've successfully done what I need to do: initiate `sudo`. No bottleneck in `c3`.

Question:

Is there a better way than typing (non-)random characters to initiate `sudo`? Is there a safe command that does nothing and so is safe to use `sudo` on?

Comment: Similar question: [Pre-authorise sudo? (So it can be run later)](https://superuser.com/q/640491/432690). I don't think it's a duplicate. You want to use `sudo` again in a minute, while the other question says "7 hours later"; therefore "angles of attack" are different. Still it's good to link the two questions together, this is the main purpose of this comment.

Comment: `sudo ls` would be fairly benign.

Comment: I use `sudo id` for this.  Although, now that I actually think about it, the natural solution would seem to be `sudo true`.

Comment: Likewise I would always just `sudo -i` and then immediately ^D out. Guess everyone has their own silly solutions encoded in habit and muscle memory.

Comment: i don't want to set up a test right now so I won't leave an answer, but (going off of my memory) using curly brackets around the commands and putting sudo in front should work. Alternatively you can use `sudo bash < <( echo 'commands' )` or something similar.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

`sudo -v` is exactly for this. From [`man 8 sudo`](https://www.sudo.ws/docs/man/sudo.man/#v):

> `-v`, `--validate`
> Update the user's cached credentials, authenticating the user if necessary. For the sudoers plugin, this extends the `sudo` timeout for another 5 minutes by default, but does not run a command. Not all security policies support cached credentials.

The complementary command is `sudo -k`, it invalidates the user's cached credentials.

While I think `sudo -v` is the Right Thing, I admit one has to remember the option to use it without consulting the manual. This is a downside. As an alternative almost any harmless command can be used with `sudo` to achieve your goal; so if you happen not to remember `-v` at the moment, use [`sudo true`](https://superuser.com/a/1762521/432690), [`sudo echo`](https://superuser.com/a/1762526/432690) or `sudo date` (credits go to the linked answers).

---

`sudo -v` should work for you in cases where your original approach works. In your example, if `command1` and `c2` take more time than it takes for `sudo` to forget the cached credentials then `sudo c3` *will* ask for your password. And so on. `sudo -v` can replace your `sudo laksdfjlskjf`, but in case of long-running command(s) preceding `sudo` neither will work.

If the line you want to run contains long-running command(s) (not excluding `sudo` commands) before some `sudo` then consider repeating `sudo -v` in the background frequently enough. Example:

```sh
sudo -v    # in the foreground, so you can input your password if needed
while sudo -v; do sleep 58; done &
command1; c2; sudo c3 | c4; c5 | sudo c6; c7; sudo c8; kill "$!"
```

Comment: Note that neither this nor OP's original solution will work for long-running commands. Password caching depends on timeouts and it can expire before the non-sudo command succeeds.

Comment: @gronostaj I silently assumed the OP wants a better replacement for `sudo laksdfjlskjf` that happens to work for them anyway. You are right. My answer now addresses the concern.

Comment: Apart from being fewer keystrokes, I wonder how `sudo -v` improves upon `sudo true`.

Comment: @reinierpost It does not run `true`, which is a separate executable and runs as a separate child process. Creating a new process is costly. But even on the fastest computer that is otherwise idle, it's more elegant not to create a new process in vain.

Comment: I like `sudo whoami`. It outputs `root` to show that it worked.

Comment: Will that `sudo -v` loop will run indefinitely if you forget about it, so if you walk away, the next person to sit down at your terminal could use `sudo` without a password?  Or if there's a limit to how long you can extend the same cached credentials, does it leave a `sudo` process in the background blocked on reading stdin (err, suspended with SIGTTIN)?  Perhaps `timeout 60m sh -c 'while ...;do; ...;done'` or something?

Comment: @PeterCordes `kill "$!"` is there to end the loop. Still if you walk away even without forgetting about the loop, a rogue can Ctrl+C the foreground command before it gets to `kill "$!"`. Note this angle of attack is possible even if you manage to use `timeout` to run the loop, unless `timeout` has already expired and cached credentials expired.

Comment: Ah, I missed the `kill "$!"`.  Yeah, as long as things go according to plan when running the set of commands, that'll do it.  But if you're going to put the `while` loop into an alias or shell-function, incorporating a timeout right into that seems like a good idea.  Like `sudo-refresh 20m &` to plan ahead to keep your sudo credentials valid for at least 20 minutes, or set a 1 hour default with no arg.  You could still kill the background job earlier at the end of your string of commands, but a timeout as a failsafe might be good for an alias for people to copy/paste.

Comment: @PeterCordes The answer is now community wiki. If you think you can improve it then please go ahead.

Comment: You didn't need to make it CW, I could have just edited since I have more than 2k rep on this site.  Also, I wasn't sure if it was good idea to introduce a dependency on `timeout` from GNU Coreutils, vs. maybe `sleep 60m && kill "$!" &` inside a shell function after putting a loop in the background.  If I get back to this and have an idea I'm happy with, I'll make an edit.

Comment: @PeterCordes I know I didn't need. My attitude is summarized in [this comment of mine](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/11740/355310#comment953392_11741).

Comment: `sudo -v` will work even if one is not authorised to run all commands in sudoers.

Answer (score 23):

How about `true`?  Description: The true utility always returns with an exit code of zero.

If you want something shorter, try `id`.  It returns user identity (and doesn't change the system in any way).

Comment: Although I think my answer (`sudo -v`) is the Right Thing, I vote this answer up because `sudo true` would be my second choice.

Comment: The shortest mostly harmless command seems to be `w`.  I don't know any command shorter than that.

Comment: one issue with running any external command (versus the internal switch -v) is that you ARE running that command, with elevated privileges. Also, you must have set up the external command as allowed to be run with sudo.

Comment: I forgot about "sudo -v".  Definitely the Right Thing. Nicely done, @KamilMaciorowski

Comment: The advantage with this solution over `sudo -v` is that if you disabled password prompting completely (by adding `username ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL` to `sudo visudo`), then `sudo -v` will ask for your password anyway whereas `sudo true` won't.

Answer (score 7):

What about a simple `echo` or `echo -n` to suppress the line break?